# How to give a path that can is common to every machine (so application want crash)

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to capture the screen and save that image into a folder, everything works fine in my local machine. I've created a setup and installed it on another machine and when i run my application it says that path is incorrect. How can i solve this code below shows how i save image and retrieve it

```
    public void capture_screen()
    {
        Size s = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 90, s);
        System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\TESTs\MyImage.jpg");
        stream.Position = 0;
        pbScreenShots.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        img =bmp;
        pbScreenShots.Image = bmp;

    }
```

How to change this path to make my setup work in any machine?

Comment: Thank you Mr. SuicideSheep ..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just write it to the `temp` folder:

```
bmp.Save(Path.GetTempPath());
```

Comment: this also works.... thanx al_Khwarizmi.. and this is the way i was looking... thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Special Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but you might need to ensure you have access to it

```
 myDocsFilePath = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments
```

Other than this, you must ensure the computer has a "TESTs" folder in my documents, and that "MyImage" doesn't already exist as you may overwrite a valued image. In short, you are probably better taking al-Khwārizmī's answer (+1!), then prompting the user to choose their own filename and destination, unless you require the picture elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Environement.UserName` property:

```
bmp.Save(string.Format(@"C:\Users\{0}\Documents\TESTs\MyImage.jpg", Environment.UserName));
```

Comment: This is wrong, the user profile doesn't have to be under C:\Users use Envrinment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)

Comment: While I do agree with your statement, the question was specific about using C:\Users as the base path.

Comment: @LucMorin - the question is "I tried with an hard-coded path and it didn't work on other machines", the answer should be "don't use an hard coded path" -- the user profile doesn't need to be under C:\Users - it's never there on XP, it's never there for the LocalSystem account and the sysadmin can move it to where ever he/she likes - your answer does not solves the asker problem (getting the code to run everywhere) only masks the problem by making his code run on other machines that are configured the same

Comment: @Nir which would be the case in a corporate environment. As I said, I agree with your statement, but I can't guess at what his setup is. If he wanted to use c:\users, maybe he had a good reason for it. Maybe I should have asked.

Answer (score 0):

Use Envrinment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) to get the user's "my document" folder, use Path.Combine to add a sub folder (you must make sure that folder exists or create it, obviously) or file name.